# Open CTI integration

Tags: integration, opencti

does Open CTI integration only work with softphones. Looking at most documentation is only mentions softphones but I have also seen where telephone systems( which to me seems to be a generalization which may include VoIP as well besides softphone) is referenced when talking about Open CTI in Salesforce [link to doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI/%22link%20to%20doc%22). We currently still use the CTI toolkit adapter with a VoIP telephone system and with the CTI toolkit being sunset soon need to cut over to the Open CTI. I have looked at the various documentation on Open CTI provided by Salesforce but since we currently have a VoIP system I was wondering if we could actually integrate it with Open CTI or must we have a softphone? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soft phone is the bridge between your telephony system and Salesforce. You can use any CTI-capable phone system, such as Avaya, AT&T, or even Skype. When you dial a number on the soft phone, it sends the command to your phone so the call can be completed. Similarly, when an incoming call starts ringing on your phone, you can answer it via the soft phone controls. Also, when caller ID is received, it pulls up the related contact or lead record. The soft phone does not "replace" your phone, it supplements your phone to provide integration with Salesforce. You can still dial from your phone, and you still need your phone's hardware to actually talk to someone (which may be a phone, a computer mic/headphone, Bluetooth, etc). Almost any digital PBX *can* work with OpenCTI, as long as it has a compatible API, although you'll want to check with your existing VoIP vendor to see if they support OpenCTI or not.

Comment: Quick question, this is amazing, we currently use twilio to send sms, and our number is voice capable, what I dont understand and I have rewatch the dreamforce video several times,not sure if there is a better one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOl-h3sUZCQ&t=2173s) is the initial login, he mentioned is not the salesforce login and it is to lock for people who should not be using it, but were can i find the user and pass? or how can i bypass this if i want all users to have access (i already add them in the call center in setup) thanks for any help

Comment: sorry i can edit my comment anymore, it is around min 20 where he mention the purpose of the login,  however do we need to build the whole auth process? or is there somewhere were you can easily add this

Comment: @manza The server needs to identify the user to associate their Salesforce session to their phone. As such, you typically can't share usernames. Each user would be set up in Twilio individually. You'll want to ask them how to accomplish that task. I'm only familiar with Cisco.

Comment: @manza you can either build it, or find a vendor that sells such a service. For example, we have a provider that has already created a package that we installed, so we didn't have to write our own auth. Try looking on the appexchange if you just want a solution and don't mind paying for it. Otherwise, you'd have to write code to get it working.